# Replace SaveFileDialog to saving in code

Tags: c#, winforms

I have such code that saves bin file, but user has to choose file

```
         Stream myStream;
         SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Binary File (*.bin)|*.bin";
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                Question.PersistObject(questions, myStream);
                myStream.Close();
            }
        }
```

But I want to choose file in code, and if a file with such name doesn't exist, then create it. How to set in `myStream` that file?

Comment: Are you looking for [`File.Open()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: are you looking to avoid the SaveFileDialog or have a filename preset in the SaveFileDialog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace all your logic related to the `OpenFileDialog` with [`File.Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
using (var myStream = File.Open(someFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    Question.PersistObject(questions, myStream);  // do something with the stream
}
```

The [`OpenOrCreate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) file mode will open the file if it exists, or create it if it does not.

The `using` statement will take care of closing the stream for you.

Comment: OP wants to **save** the file, not open it.   Your answer doesn't seem applicable....

Comment: You might want to explain how to wrap it in a using statement.

Comment: @Tim You are correct, the OP wants to save. But you have to open the file for writing with a stream. So Grant is correct.

Comment: @GrantWinney - Got it, thanks.  Didn't read closely enough the first time.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to have a base name and append a number:

```
string templateName = "myfile{0}.bin";
string finalName;
int count = 0;
do {
    finalName = String.Format(templateName, count++);
} while (File.Exists(finalName);
```

Or, if you don't care about the name, use [Path.GetTempFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Then pass that name to StreamWriter:

```
 using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(finalName))
 {
      // Write stuff
 }
```